# Java using regex split to put string into array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I am trying to put a String into an array so I can print the tokens in a different order to how they are in the original file which I am reading from.

Below is the code I have so far, I have also included the input file I am reading from. What I would like to be able to do is print one word from the original file; 
system.out.println(tokens[4]); 
Which would print 'Species'

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class inClassTest4Time {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scan = new  
Scanner(inClassTest4Time.class.getResourcesAsStream("pet.txt"));
String line;
String[] tokens;
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        line = (scan.nextLine());
        tokens = line.split("//s");
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(tokens[i]);

        }

    }


}
}
```

Input File:

```
Pet
===================
- species : String
+ isChipped : boolean
- name : String
- age : int
===================
+ Pet ( String name )
===================
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant to put `\\s` instead of `//s`. `//s` is actually splitting based on the literal string `//s` (ie no escaping). Since none of your strings have that, there is no split. I suspect that if you do `tokens[2]` you will get `- species : String`.

Comment: Ive changed it, i get the below output if  i put system.out.println(tokens[4]);    I get this output: Pet Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 at InClassTest4.inClassTest4Time.main(inClassTest4Time.java:19) Java Result: 1

Comment: Yes, that's because in Java arrays are zero based, so for four tokens you would get token index 0, 1, 2 and 3.